# from webview to activity

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

I have a login form in the webview and I need to ensure that when the correct data is entered, the user is directed to activity  MainActivity.java.

```
  $(function() {
  $('.submit').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var inp1 = $('#inp1').val();
    var inp2 = $('#inp2').val();
    var url = "";
    if (inp1 == 'exmp@mail.ru' && inp2 == 'exp111') {
      document.location.href =  url;
    } else {
      $('.err').html('incorrect!');
    }
  });
});


 <div class="log_in">
        <p class="err"></p>
        <input id="inp1" type="email" name="name" placeholder="mail" required><br>
        <input id="inp2"  type="password" name="pass" placeholder="pass" required><br><br><br>
        <a  class="submit"  href="">Login</a></div>
```

Comment: Have you read https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html? It explains how to bind Activity with WebView.

Answer (score 0):

I guess You can use DeepLinks.
in summarize you can set some keywords in the Url and whenever someone opens that link, your SELECTED Activity will be opened.

check :

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html

and also :

[tutplus](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-enable-deep-links-on-android--cms-26317)